# OCR image in .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, image-manipulation, ocr

Is there any library or code samples to convert an image to text in the .net compact framework?
I have seen an app on a mobile phone that you can take a picutre of a business card and it will auto fill in a contact record so I know it is possible but I was wondering how to do it.  I searched google and can't seem to find anything specific for the compact framework, does anyone out there have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OCR is a tricky beast, which is why you probably won't find many free, high-quality, OCR engines.   The OCR app on your phone (I'm guessing it's an HTC phone with WorldCard Mobile?) probably has an extremely-well-protected OCR engine or it farms out the work via a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, one option could be to compile the Tesserac project (http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr) into a native dll for your target device and using this dll with p/Invoke from .NetCF.